How to flush only a single float
I want to flush only a single float also using \afterpage. I am aware that \clearpage flushes all remaining floats but I do not want that since the second float in my case does not take up the entire page and should be placed together with text on that page.
I expected that \clearpage just needs to be stopped after the first float is flushed but Since I do not really now how to do that at all, I tried chatgpt but the result is underwhelming because the code seems to behave just like \clearpage although chatgpt claims to be correct. I included the code below as a MWE and, possibly, as a starting point for solutions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\flushsinglefloat}{%
  \begingroup
  % If no pending floats, do nothing
  \ifx\@toplist\@empty
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty
      \ifx\@dbltoplist\@empty
        \ifx\@deferlist\@empty
          % No floats to process
        \else
          % Force processing of the first deferred float
          \@processfloat\@deferlist
        \fi
      \else
        % Force processing of the first double-column float
        \@processfloat\@dbltoplist
      \fi
    \else
      % Force processing of the first bottom float
      \@processfloat\@botlist
    \fi
  \else
    % Force processing of the first top float
    \@processfloat\@toplist
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

% Helper to process the first float from the list
\newcommand{\@processfloat}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter\@elt\expandafter{#1}}%
  \global\let#1\@empty % Remove the float from the list after processing
  \@outputpage % Finalize the page layout
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{A test figure 1.}
\end{figure}
\afterpage{\flushsinglefloat} % Force the above figure to be placed immediately
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
  \caption{A test figure 2.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


The probablility that chatgpt gives correct code for latex document code is small, the chance that it gives correct code to modify the latex output routine is essentially zero I would expect.

figure 1 comes on page 2 if you remove %\afterpage{\flushsinglefloat}  isn't that what you want?

Yes, a chatgpt success was not expected especially for something I could not find online myself... I used it to get the \clearpage code and maybe some first attempt at it hoping I could figure it out on my own from there..

My real example is of course a bit different, but yes, here the float may be placed there anyway.


You don't need to flush figure 1 at all as it just naturally comes on the next page. I Would guess that your concern is that figure 2 comes on a page on its own, that goes to a float page as it is larger than \floatpagefraction so you could increase that which might have effects elsewhere so simpler is just to remove the p option for that float.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{A test figure 1.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
    \lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
  \caption{A test figure 2.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

Alternatively you can avoid adding [t] to figure 2 and  tell LaTeX to always try to make the last pending floats fit on a text page rather than a float page by loading fewerfloatpages so change your preamble to
\usepackage{afterpage,lipsum,fewerfloatpages}

which produces the same output as above without needing [t]

Yes, that seems to solve the problem for me here. Yet, I wonder what the journal will say about fewerfloatpages...

I still feel that a flush-n-floats macro/package could be very often helpful as I see many such afterpage+clearpage+placeins questions being asked in general.

@RonnieMarksch I think 99% of uses of afterpage would be better not using it. I wrote it to understand grouping in the output routine, it didn't occur to me that people would use it, and still be using it 30 years later.
